# How to correct mouse pointer misalignment in screen recording on external 4K display in ChromeOS?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screenshot, chromebook, google-chrome-os

**Problem**: The mouse cursor is in the wrong position on screen recordings I make with my Chromebook *but* only when the recording is done of my external monitor. Take a look:

[image: ChromeOS screen recording showing mouse cursor position is wrong]

This is a high DPI 4K monitor that I can attach via HDMI or through a USB-C hub but the result is the same in either case. I noticed this previously with my Pixelbook Go but I'm currently using a [Frame.work Laptop](https://frame.work) and it's rather irritating because the only work-around I've found is to use the built-in screen anytime I'm doing recordings.

[image: Display devices on my Chromebook]